# PowerBI: Calculate Median, Q1 and Q3 in an aggregated table at the lowest common denominator

Tags: powerbi, aggregate, visualization, median, percentile

I'm currently facing a problem for which I haven't found a solution on the forum.

I'm working on an aggregated table containing information such as the installation region, departmental perimeter, lot number, contract number , meter brand, diameter, age since installation, and installation year.
This table allows me to know the number of meters as well as the sum of their performance for each unique combination of this information.

I managed to calculate the average age of the lots for each departmental perimeter using the following formula:
SUM((Age of meters * number of meters)/ SUM(number of meters)

The results obtained are consistent, and I was able to integrate them into a matrix for visualization.
However, I'm now faced with a new challenge: calculating the median age, Q1, and Q3 for each lots of each departmental meters.

The structure of the table makes this task a bit more complex, and I'm therefore looking for help to achieve this.
If someone has skills in PowerBI and can help me solve this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

I have already tried using the Median function on the age column, but it does not take into account the number of counters for each combination of lot and perimeter

Comment: This is a question and answer site.  So you need to provide enough information in the form of sample data, and desired results to get an answer.

Comment: And generally if "The structure of the table makes this task a bit more complex" then consider restructuring the data in Power Query to make it easier.  The measure of a good data model is the ease of querying it.  See eg: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema